# ARP implementation

Tags: performance, c, linked-list, linux, networking

I am a beginner in C and wrote this code to implement ARP.

3 threads are present - one to respond/receive any ARP packet targeted to me, one to refresh the ARP table on a periodic basis, and one to transmit packets present in the buffer.

An ARP table is implemented in a hash table. The sensitive areas are:

1. A reply needs to be sent as soon as a request is received.
2. An ARP table lookup should be very fast.

Please share your suggestions to improve the performance of the code. Also, please suggest some easier ways/tools to measure and share performance/machine cycles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define ETH_HW_ADDR_LEN  6
#define IP_ADDR_LEN      4
#define ARP_ETHERTYPE    0x0806
#define ETHER_HW_TYPE    1
#define IP_ETHERTYPE     0x0800
#define ETH_ADDR_LEN     6

//The following opcodes are actually 0x0001 and 0x0002. It is written in Network byte order

#define ARP_REQ_OPCODE   0x0100
#define ARP_RES_OPCODE   0x0200

#define ARP_RESPONSE_WAITTIME 1       //TIME to wait for arp reponse in seconds
#define ARP_NUMBER_OF_TRIES 3         //Number of times ARP request need to be sent if reply not received
#define ARP_TIMEOUT 30                //seconds till an ARP entry is valid
#define ARP_REFRESHER_PERIODICITY 60  //Periodicity of ARP refresher in seconds

#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE 1000  //size of tx buffer
#define ARP_TABLE_SIZE 1000  //size of ARP lookup table

typedef struct ethernet_header {

  uint8_t dst_mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN];
  uint8_t src_mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN];

}ethernet_header;

typedef struct arp_header {

  uint16_t ethertype;
  uint16_t hw_type;
  uint16_t protocol_type;
  uint8_t  hw_addr_size;
  uint8_t  protocol_addr_size;
  uint16_t opcode;
  uint8_t  sender_mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN];
  uint8_t  sender_ip[IP_ADDR_LEN];
  uint8_t  target_mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN];
  uint8_t  target_ip[IP_ADDR_LEN];
  uint8_t  padding[18];

}arp_header;

typedef struct ARP_packet {

  ethernet_header eth_h;
  arp_header arp_h;

}Tx_packet;

typedef struct Tx_buff {

      Tx_packet *Tx_array[TX_BUFFER_SIZE];
      int head;
      int tail;

}Tx_buff;

typedef struct ARP_entry {

    uint8_t  ip[IP_ADDR_LEN];
    uint8_t  mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN];
    /* This variable can be incremented periodically to determine how old is an entry*/
    uint16_t howOld;
    struct ARP_entry *next;

}ARP_entry_t;

/* Functions */

/* general functions*/
void  *allocateMemory(int);
/* Functions related to ARP Table*/
bool  initializeARPTable();
int   ARPTableLookupHashFunction(uint8_t[]);
bool  ARPTableInsert(uint8_t [], uint8_t[]);
bool  ARPTableLookup( uint8_t[], uint8_t[]);
bool  deleteARPTable();
bool  showAllARPEntries();
/* Tx buffer and Transmission*/
bool  insertTxBuffer(Tx_packet*);
void  *Transmission();
/* related to ARP initiator and responder*/
void  createArpHeader(int);
void  *ARP_responder();
bool  ARP_initiator(uint8_t[]);
/* related to ARP refresher*/
ARP_entry_t *deleteOldEntries(ARP_entry_t*);
bool  refreshARPTable();
void  *ARP_refresher();


//Tx Buffer where ARP_initiator would place all the requests to be sent.
Tx_buff Tx_buffer = { .head = 0, .tail = -1 };

void **ARP_Table=NULL; //datastructure to store ARP entries.

time_t referenceTime=0; //the time at which the program starts
time_t lastRefreshedTime=0;
int noOfARPEntries = 0; //stores the number of arp entries present in the ARP table.

int socId;         //raw socket id
char *ifname=NULL; //input interface name
uint8_t initiatedIp[IP_ADDR_LEN] = {0}; // the IP for which ARP request is initiated

ethernet_header *eth; // ready packet with default values constructed using createArpHeader API.

//Variable which stores the status of the ARP responder and Transmission threads.
bool threadRunning=1;

/*****************************************************************************************
 * Function : allocateMemory()                                                        *
 * DESCRIPTION: This function is used to allocate memory using malloc. In case memory not
            available, it will throw error.                                                *
 * Args: int size : size of the memory block
 * Return Type: Void Pointer                                                            *
 * **************************************************************************************/

void* allocateMemory(int size)
{
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if((ptr=malloc(size))== NULL)
    {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory");
            exit;
    }
   return ptr;
}

bool initializeARPTable()
{
    int i;
    /* Allocate memory to hold ARP_TABLE_SIZE number of pointers*/
    ARP_Table=allocateMemory(sizeof(void *) * ARP_TABLE_SIZE);
    /* Initialize all pointer to NULL*/
    for(i=0;i<=ARP_TABLE_SIZE;i++)
        ARP_Table[i] = NULL;
    return 1;
}

int ARPTableLookupHashFunction(uint8_t ip[IP_ADDR_LEN])
{
    return ip[2];  //hash function is the last byte of the IP address
}

bool ARPTableInsert(uint8_t ip[IP_ADDR_LEN], uint8_t mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN])
{
    int ARPTableIndex = ARPTableLookupHashFunction(ip); //get the index using hash function.
    ARP_entry_t *node  = (ARP_entry_t *)ARP_Table[ARPTableIndex];

    /* check whether IP already exists*/
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if(
                ip[0] == node->ip[0] &&
                ip[1] == node->ip[1] &&
                ip[2] == node->ip[2] &&
                ip[3] == node->ip[3]
        )break;

        node=node->next;

    }
    /*if node is not NULL, a matching IP is found*/
    if(node != NULL) {
        //memcpy(node->mac, mac, ETH_ADDR_LEN);
        node->mac[0] = mac[0];
        node->mac[1] = mac[1];
        node->mac[2] = mac[2];
        node->mac[3] = mac[3];
        node->mac[4] = mac[4];
        node->mac[5] = mac[5];
        /*update the timer to current time*/
        node->howOld = (uint16_t)(time(NULL) - referenceTime);
        return 1;
    }
    /* if no matching IP found, create a new node. */
    ARP_entry_t *newnode = allocateMemory(sizeof(ARP_entry_t));

    //insert the newnode
    newnode->next = ARP_Table[ARPTableIndex];  //newnode->next will point to the address pointed by the table.

    newnode->ip[0]=ip[0];
    newnode->ip[1]=ip[1];
    newnode->ip[2]=ip[2];
    newnode->ip[3]=ip[3];

    newnode->mac[0]=mac[0];
    newnode->mac[1]=mac[1];
    newnode->mac[2]=mac[2];
    newnode->mac[3]=mac[3];
    newnode->mac[4]=mac[4];
    newnode->mac[5]=mac[5];

    newnode->howOld = (uint16_t)(time(NULL) - referenceTime);

    ARP_Table[ARPTableIndex] = newnode;  //Table will have the address of the newnode.
    ++noOfARPEntries; //increment the number of entries present
    return 1;
}

bool ARPTableLookup( uint8_t inputIp[IP_ADDR_LEN], uint8_t resolvedMac[ETH_ADDR_LEN] )
{
    int ARPTableIndex = ARPTableLookupHashFunction(inputIp);
    int noOfTries = ARP_NUMBER_OF_TRIES; // number of times arp request to be resent in case reply not received

    ARP_entry_t *node = NULL, *nextNode = NULL;

    LOOKUP: //LOOKUP label is used to lookup the table again and again after sending ARP request again and again.
        node  = (ARP_entry_t *)ARP_Table[ARPTableIndex];

        while(node != NULL)
        {
            nextNode = node->next;
            /* If given IP matches IP of the node*/
            if(
                    inputIp[0]==node->ip[0] &&
                    inputIp[1]==node->ip[1] &&
                    inputIp[2]==node->ip[2] &&
                    inputIp[3]==node->ip[3]

              ){
                /* If the entry has timed out, break from the loop to send ARP requests*/
                if( (time(NULL) - (node->howOld + referenceTime)) > ARP_TIMEOUT )
                {
                    //free(node);
                    break;
                }
                /* if the entry has not timed out, return the output mac*/
                resolvedMac[0]=node->mac[0];
                resolvedMac[1]=node->mac[1];
                resolvedMac[2]=node->mac[2];
                resolvedMac[3]=node->mac[3];
                resolvedMac[4]=node->mac[4];
                resolvedMac[5]=node->mac[5];
                return 1;

            }
            node=nextNode;

        }
    /* when the no of retries has been reached, keep sending ARP request for configured no. of times and LOOKUP*/
    if(noOfTries--) {

        ARP_initiator(inputIp);
        sleep(ARP_RESPONSE_WAITTIME);
        goto LOOKUP;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Function is used to delete the entire ARP hash Table*/
bool deleteARPTable()
{
    int i;
    ARP_entry_t *currentNode, *nextNode;
    for(i=0; i < ARP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        currentNode=ARP_Table[i];
        while (currentNode != NULL)
        {
            nextNode = currentNode->next;
            free(currentNode);
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
        ARP_Table[i] = NULL;
    }
    noOfARPEntries = 0; //set number of entries present as 0
    return 1;
}

/* Function is used to display all the ARP entries present in the ARP Table*/
bool showAllARPEntries()
{
    int i,j=1;
    ARP_entry_t *node;

    printf("s.no.\tIP ADDRESS\t\tMAC ADDRESS\t\tAge in sec\n");

    for(i=0; i < ARP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        node=ARP_Table[i];
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d    \t%d.%d.%d.%d\t\t%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\t    %d\n",j,node->ip[0],node->ip[1],node->ip[2],node->ip[3],node->mac[0],node->mac[1],node->mac[2],node->mac[3],node->mac[4],node->mac[5],time(NULL) - (node->howOld + referenceTime) );
            ++j;
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Function used to insert an ARP request/reply into the Tx buffer*/
bool insertTxBuffer(Tx_packet *packetIntoBuffer)
{
    /*If the head is equal to tail, then there is no space in the buffer. Otherwsie append the packet in the buffer and move head to next position*/
    if( (Tx_buffer.head % TX_BUFFER_SIZE) != Tx_buffer.tail )
    {
        Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.head] = packetIntoBuffer;
        Tx_buffer.head=++Tx_buffer.head % TX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Unable to insert into Tx Buffer since the buffer is full.\n");
    return 0;

}

/* This thread is used to read the Tx buffer and send packets whenever present*/
void *Transmission()
{
    int tx_length;
    char *opcode_type=allocateMemory(sizeof(char *) * 10);

    while(1 && threadRunning)
    {
        /* If the next position of tail is equal to head, there is no packet in the buffer. Otherwise, increment tail and send the packet*/
        if(((Tx_buffer.tail+1) % TX_BUFFER_SIZE )!=Tx_buffer.head)
        {
            Tx_buffer.tail=(++Tx_buffer.tail) % TX_BUFFER_SIZE;
            tx_length=write(socId, Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail], sizeof(Tx_packet));

            //Check whether it is request or reply to print
            if(((Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail])->arp_h).opcode == ARP_REQ_OPCODE) { strcpy(opcode_type, "request"); } else { strcpy(opcode_type, "reply");}

            if(-1 == tx_length)
            {
                printf(" write error.Unable to write in the socket.\n");
                return NULL;
            } else {

                printf(" ARP %s sent to %d.%d.%d.%d \n", opcode_type, ( ( Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail] )->arp_h ).target_ip[0],
                                                         ( ( Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail] )->arp_h ).target_ip[1],
                                                         ( ( Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail] )->arp_h ).target_ip[2],
                                                         ( ( Tx_buffer.Tx_array[Tx_buffer.tail] )->arp_h ).target_ip[3]);
            }


        }
        //wait for 1 ms.
        usleep(1000);
    }
    //free memory
    if(opcode_type != NULL) free(opcode_type);
    return NULL;
}

/*****************************************************************************************
 * Function : createArpHeader()                                                        *
 * DESCRIPTION: This function is used to create ARP header which will be used by
            ARP_responder() and ARP_initiator.

 * Args: opcode : ARP_RES_OPCODE or ARP_REQ_OPCODE
 * **************************************************************************************/

void createArpHeader(int opcode)
{
    eth = (ethernet_header *)allocateMemory(sizeof(ethernet_header)+sizeof(arp_header));
    arp_header *arp = (arp_header *)(eth+1);

    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
        struct ifreq ifr;
    int i;

    bzero(&sll, sizeof(sll));
    bzero(&ifr, sizeof(ifr));
    bzero(eth, sizeof(ethernet_header)+sizeof(arp_header));


// GET INTERFACE INDEX
        strncpy((char *)ifr.ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ);
        if((ioctl(socId, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error in getting Interface index !\nPlease configure correct interface\n");
                return;
        }
// GET MAC ADDRESS
        if((ioctl(socId, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr)) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error in getting Interface MAC !\nPlease configure correct interface\n");
                return;
        }

    memcpy(&(eth->src_mac), ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memset(&(eth->dst_mac), 0xff, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

//GET IP ADDRESS
        if((ioctl(socId, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr)) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error in getting Interface MAC !\nPlease configure correct interface\n");
                return;
        }
//FORM ARP HEADER
    arp->ethertype          = htons(ETH_P_ARP);
    arp->hw_type            = htons(ETHER_HW_TYPE);
    arp->protocol_type      = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    arp->hw_addr_size       = ETH_HW_ADDR_LEN;
    arp->protocol_addr_size = IP_ADDR_LEN;
    arp->opcode             = opcode;

    memcpy (&(arp->sender_mac), &(eth->src_mac), 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memcpy (&(arp->sender_ip),  &((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr, 4 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memset (&(arp->target_mac), 0x00, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memset (&(arp->target_ip),  0x00, 4 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    bzero(&(arp->padding), 18);

//BIND RAW SOCKET to the INTERFACE

        sll.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
        sll.sll_ifindex  = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
        sll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ARP);

        if((bind(socId, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll)))== -1)
        {
                printf("Error: Could not bind raw socket to interface\n");
                return;
        }

}
/*****************************************************************************************
 * Function : ARP_responder()                                                        *
 * DESCRIPTION: This function listens all ARP packets in the socket and send ARP reply
            if the request is destined to the specified interface                  *
 * Args: none.
 * Return Type: Void Pointer                                                            *
 * **************************************************************************************/

void* ARP_responder()
{

//rx_eth_header is to store the received ARP request and tx_eth_header is to store the ARP reply to be transmitted.

    ethernet_header *rx_eth_header = allocateMemory((sizeof(ethernet_header)+sizeof(arp_header)));
    arp_header *rx_arp=(arp_header *)(rx_eth_header+1);

    int rx_length, tx_length, i;

//call createArpHeader to create ARP response
    createArpHeader(ARP_RES_OPCODE);

    ethernet_header *tx_eth_header=allocateMemory(sizeof(ethernet_header)+sizeof(arp_header));
    arp_header *tx_arp=(arp_header *)(tx_eth_header+1);
    memcpy(tx_eth_header,eth, sizeof(ethernet_header)+sizeof(arp_header));

    //Until we receive packets and thread status is ON
    while(((rx_length=recvfrom(socId, rx_eth_header, sizeof(arp_header)+sizeof(ethernet_header), 0, NULL, NULL))>0) && threadRunning ) {

            if(
                //Check whether TARGET IP is my IP.

                rx_arp->target_ip[3]==tx_arp->sender_ip[3] &&
                rx_arp->target_ip[2]==tx_arp->sender_ip[2] &&
                rx_arp->target_ip[1]==tx_arp->sender_ip[1] &&
            rx_arp->target_ip[0]==tx_arp->sender_ip[0]

        )
        {
            // Check whether its a ARP Request. If so, send ARP Reply.
            if(rx_arp->opcode==ARP_REQ_OPCODE)
                {
                    // Copy his MAC and IP to my ARP reply
                            tx_arp->target_mac[0]=rx_arp->sender_mac[0];
                tx_arp->target_mac[1]=rx_arp->sender_mac[1];
                tx_arp->target_mac[2]=rx_arp->sender_mac[2];
                tx_arp->target_mac[3]=rx_arp->sender_mac[3];
                tx_arp->target_mac[4]=rx_arp->sender_mac[4];
                tx_arp->target_mac[5]=rx_arp->sender_mac[5];

                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[0]=tx_arp->target_mac[0];
                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[1]=tx_arp->target_mac[1];
                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[2]=tx_arp->target_mac[2];
                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[3]=tx_arp->target_mac[3];
                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[4]=tx_arp->target_mac[4];
                tx_eth_header->dst_mac[5]=tx_arp->target_mac[5];

                    tx_arp->target_ip[0]=rx_arp->sender_ip[0];
                tx_arp->target_ip[1]=rx_arp->sender_ip[1];
                tx_arp->target_ip[2]=rx_arp->sender_ip[2];
                tx_arp->target_ip[3]=rx_arp->sender_ip[3];

                //Append ARP reply packet to the Tx_buffer
                insertTxBuffer((Tx_packet *)tx_eth_header);
                //Add his MAC details into ARP table
                ARPTableInsert(rx_arp->sender_ip, rx_arp->sender_mac);

                printf("Received ARP request from %d.%d.%d.%d\n",tx_arp->target_ip[0], tx_arp->target_ip[1], tx_arp->target_ip[2], tx_arp->target_ip[3]);

            }
            //If its an ARP Reply && check whether 'target_ip' matches the IP we initiated.
            else if(
                rx_arp->opcode==ARP_RES_OPCODE &&
                rx_arp->sender_ip[3]==initiatedIp[3] &&
                        rx_arp->sender_ip[2]==initiatedIp[2] &&
                rx_arp->sender_ip[1]==initiatedIp[1] &&
                rx_arp->sender_ip[0]==initiatedIp[0]

            )
            {  //Insert into the ARP_Table
               ARPTableInsert(initiatedIp,rx_arp->sender_mac);
               printf("%d.%d.%d.%d is at %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n", initiatedIp[0],initiatedIp[1],initiatedIp[2],initiatedIp[3],rx_arp->sender_mac[0],rx_arp->sender_mac[1],rx_arp->sender_mac[2],rx_arp->sender_mac[3],rx_arp->sender_mac[4],rx_arp->sender_mac[5]);
            }
         } else continue;

    }
    if(threadRunning) {
            printf("Unable to receive from socket\n");
    }
    close(socId);

//FREE all POINTERS

    free(rx_eth_header);
    free(tx_eth_header);
    rx_eth_header=NULL;
    tx_eth_header=NULL;
    if(eth!=NULL){
            free(eth);
            eth=NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*****************************************************************************************
 * Function : ARP_initiator()                                                        *
 * DESCRIPTION: This function is used to send ARP request
 * Args: none.
 * **************************************************************************************/

bool ARP_initiator(uint8_t target_ip[IP_ADDR_LEN])
{
    int tx_length;
    int i;

//The pointer 'eth' already has the ARP request format. Only Target IP and Opcode need to be updated.

    memcpy( &((arp_header *)(eth+1))->target_ip, target_ip, IP_ADDR_LEN);
    ((arp_header *)(eth+1))->opcode=ARP_REQ_OPCODE ;

    // Insert into Tx buffer
    insertTxBuffer((Tx_packet *)eth);
    return 1;
}

/*This function will recursively called to delete old/timeout entries in a list of entries*/
ARP_entry_t *deleteOldEntries(ARP_entry_t *currentNode)
{

    ARP_entry_t *nextNode;
    nextNode = currentNode->next;

    if ( nextNode->next != NULL )
    {
        deleteOldEntries(nextNode); //recursive call until node before last node is reached.

    }
    /* In case of timeout, delete the node*/
    if(((time(NULL) - (nextNode->howOld + referenceTime)) > ARP_TIMEOUT))
    {
        printf("ARP entry for %d.%d.%d.%d has expired\n", nextNode->ip[0],  nextNode->ip[1], nextNode->ip[2], nextNode->ip[3]);
        currentNode->next = nextNode->next;
        free(nextNode); nextNode = NULL;
        --noOfARPEntries; //decrement the no. of arp entries

    }
    //printf("return pointer of function is %p\n", currentNode);
    return currentNode;
}

/*This fiunction will refresh the ARP table*/
bool refreshARPTable()
{
    int i;
    ARP_entry_t *dummyNode = allocateMemory(sizeof(ARP_entry_t));

    printf("Refreshing ARP entries...\n");
    for(i=0;i<ARP_TABLE_SIZE;i++){
        if(ARP_Table[i] != NULL)
        {
            dummyNode->next = ARP_Table[i]; // a dummy node is created such that its next node is the first node of the list.
            ARP_Table[i] = (deleteOldEntries(dummyNode))->next; // dummy node will be returned by the function. Its next pointer would have the actual first node.
        }
    }
    lastRefreshedTime = time(NULL);
    if(dummyNode != NULL)
        free(dummyNode);
    return 1;
}

/* This thread will periodically trigger refreshARPTable function for every 'ARP_REFRESHER_PERIODICITY' seconds */
void* ARP_refresher()
{
    while(threadRunning)
    {
        //sleep to maintain periodicity
        sleep(ARP_REFRESHER_PERIODICITY);
        /* start refreshing if the current time is higher than the last refreshed time and no. of ARP entries is atleast one*/
        if(noOfARPEntries && ((time(NULL) - lastRefreshedTime) > ARP_REFRESHER_PERIODICITY))
            refreshARPTable();
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifname = allocateMemory(10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(ifname,argv[2]);

    uint8_t *target_mac=(uint8_t *)allocateMemory(sizeof(uint8_t) * ETH_ADDR_LEN);

    initializeARPTable();
    referenceTime=time(NULL);     //time of start of the program acts as a reference for every ARP entries
    lastRefreshedTime = time(NULL); // time at which ARP table was refreshed
//Create Raw socket
    socId = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (socId == -1)
    {
            printf("Error in creating raw socket");
            return 0;
    }

//Create ARP responder thread
    pthread_t thread1,thread2,thread3;
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,Transmission,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,ARP_responder,NULL);
    usleep(10000);
    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL,ARP_refresher,NULL);

    //char *input=malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    char *input = NULL;
        input = allocateMemory (30 * sizeof(char));
    printf(">");
    while(fgets(input,30*sizeof(char),stdin) != NULL)
    {
            switch (input[0])
            {
                    case 's':
                            //Convert IP address to numeric format
                inet_aton(&input[9],initiatedIp);
                            ARP_initiator(initiatedIp);
                            break;
                    case '?':
                            printf("\nsend_arp <Target_IP>");
                printf("\nlookup <target_ip>");
                printf("\nview arp table");
                    printf("\ndelete arp table");
                    printf("\nrefresh arp table");
                printf("\nexit\n");
                            printf("\n>");
                            break;
            case 'l':
                inet_aton(&input[7],initiatedIp);
                if(ARPTableLookup( initiatedIp,target_mac ))
                     printf("%d.%d.%d.%d is at %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n", initiatedIp[0],initiatedIp[1],initiatedIp[2],initiatedIp[3],target_mac[0],target_mac[1],target_mac[2],target_mac[3],target_mac[4],target_mac[5]);
                else
                    printf("Lookup failed! No such ARP entry.\n");
                printf(">");
                break;
            case 'd':
                deleteARPTable();
            case 'v':
                showAllARPEntries();
                printf(">");
                break;
            case 'r':
                refreshARPTable();
                printf(">");
                break;
            case 'e':
                            threadRunning=0; //CLOSE RESPONDER THREAD;
                usleep(500000);//wait for child thread to get teminated.
                deleteARPTable();//delete all the ARP entries
                            //usleep(500000);
                free(ARP_Table);   ARP_Table = NULL;
                free(input);       input = NULL;
                free(target_mac);  target_mac = NULL;
                free(ifname);      ifname = NULL;
                            return 0;
                    default:
                            printf(">");

            }
    }

        return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
-bash-3.2# ./arp_karthik.o -i eth0
>
>?
send_arp <Target_IP>
lookup <target_ip>
view arp table
delete arp table
refresh arp table
exit

>send_arp 192.168.10.1
 ARP request sent to 192.168.10.1
 192.168.10.1 is at 00:ff:f2:c8:03:88

>send_arp 192.168.10.13
  ARP request sent to 192.168.10.13
  192.168.10.13 is at 00:30:48:9a:2e:14

>view arp table
  s.no.   IP ADDRESS              MAC ADDRESS             Age in sec
  1       192.168.10.13           00:30:48:9a:2e:14           8
  2       192.168.10.1             00:ff:f2:c8:03:88             18
>
>delete arp table
  s.no.   IP ADDRESS              MAC ADDRESS             Age in sec

>send_arp 192.168.12.217
   ARP request sent to 192.168.12.217
   192.168.12.217 is at 00:ff:f2:c8:03:88

>Refreshing ARP entries...
   ARP entry for 192.168.12.217 has expired

>view arp table
s.no.   IP ADDRESS              MAC ADDRESS             Age in sec
>
>
```

Answer (score 5):

- **UB**

  Constructs like

  ```
      Tx_buffer.head=++Tx_buffer.head % TX_BUFFER_SIZE
  ```

  invoke undefined behaviour. Technically this makes the code broken.
- **Thread safety**

  is not there. Shared structures `ARP_Table` and `TX_buffer` are accessed by multiple threads with no synchronization whatsoever. A disaster waiting to happen.
- **Buggy responder**

  `ARP_responder` creates only one instance of `tx_eth_header`, but inserts it into the `TX_buffer` in the loop. Meaning that the buffer may contain multiple pointers to the same instance. Meaning that all of them point to the same `dst_mac`. Meaning that the responder may respond with the wrong data.
- **Too many allocations**

  For objects as small as `APR_entry_t`, `opcode_type`, `ethernet_header`, etc. an allocate/free within same scope only leads to heap fragmentation. It is perfectly safe to keep them as local variables.
- **Endianness**

  > //The following opcodes are actually 0x0001 and 0x0002. It is written in Network byte order

  Not so. It is only in a network byte order on a little endian machine. On a big endian machine code will break. Define them naturally `0x0001, 0x0002` and use `htons` as for any other value.
- **Refresh**

  Old entry deletion is weird. I don't see the need for `dummyEntry` and/or recursion.
- **More**

  There are many more objections which are irrelevant until major problems are fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vnp. Will update soon after fixing these major issues.

Comment: @Karthik Please roll back the fixes - this invalidates the review. You are welcome to post the fixed code in the follow-up question.

Comment: sure, could you please say how to roll back and what is a follow-up question

Comment: @Karthik I rolled it back. A follow-up question is just a regular question, preferably with a link to the initial question. For example, "I posted a such-and-such question (make it a hyperlink), here is an updated version of the code".